# How to generate serial number for duplicate ids in SQL Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to generate an extra column in SQL Query,
that adds suffix as "serial number" for distinguishing duplicate ids?

E.g: Expected Output

```
id     (extra column)    value
----------------------------
10000      10000-1        
10000      10000-2    
10001      10001-1       
10001      10001-2   
10002      10002-1        
10003      10003-1     
10003      10003-2
10003      10003-3
```

How to get the result as above formatted output.

Comment: which version of mysql you are using ? Is this required in select query result ?

Comment: @AmitVerma I am actually using "Google BigQuery" to run this query because the date are huge. But I am not sure about the compatibility.

Comment: Check RANK() OVER PARTITON BY Syntax in Bigquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select *, id || '-' || row_number() over(partition by id) extra_column
from table
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Is big query similar to MySQL? Is there any free online platform to practice and understand it.

Comment: Thanks Sir...can you please let me know how any one can learn and practice this.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/how-to    :o)